# SwiftUI View not updating when @ObservedObject changes using GCD

Tags: ios, swiftui, grand-central-dispatch

I'm still in the early stages with SwiftUI. Everything's been fine up until now, but I'm running into problems with using GCD - never worked with multi-threading before.

I am getting data from various sensors over TCP continuously running in the background. All this seems fine, I can see the data coming across and it appears to be getting stored where I want it...

Raw data

> $AIMTW,26.1,C*1E

Contents of struct

> (src: "AI", timeStamp: 2021-09-11 10:43:01 +0000, temp: 26.1, units: "ºC")

I *think* I'm getting the data processing happening on the main thread where it should update my View, but it doesn't update. I expect I've missed something pretty fundamental, but I just can't work out what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

This should hopefully be enough to reproduce the problem. Originally the code would be reading in a constant stream of data from a TCP source; I have modified it to read from a text file. The View should update after each line of the text file.

```
import Foundation

struct NMEA{
    // Mean Temperature of Water
    var mtw = (src: "",                 // Source
               timeStamp: Date(),       // Generated Time Stamp
               temp: 0.0,               // temperature
               units: "")               // unit of measurement, Celsius (C)
    }
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var nmeaHandler = NMEAhandler()
        
    var body: some View {
            HStack{
                Text("Water Temperature: ")
                Text(String(nmeaHandler.nmea.mtw.temp))
                Text(nmeaHandler.nmea.mtw.units)
            }
        .onAppear{
            nmeaHandler.fetchNMEA()
        }
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation

class NMEAhandler: ObservableObject{
    @Published var nmea = NMEA()
    
    func fetchNMEA() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {            self.receiveNMEA()
        }
    }
    
    private func receiveNMEA() {
        do {
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "reprex-input", ofType: "txt") ?? "" // file path for file "data.txt"
            let message = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print(message)
            message.enumerateLines(invoking: { (line, stop) -> () in
                print("Line = \(line)")
            })
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.prepareSentences(data: message)
                print("The View updates now.")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error:", error)
        }
    }

    private func prepareSentences(data: String){
        var messages: [String] = []
        var fields: [String] = []
        if data != "-"{
            messages = data.components(separatedBy: "\r\n")
            for message in messages{
                fields = message.components(separatedBy: ",")
                let lastField = fields.last
                let splitLast = lastField?.components(separatedBy: "*") ?? [""]
                fields.removeLast(1)
                fields.append(contentsOf: splitLast)
                let valid = checksum(message: message, checksum: fields.last ?? "")
                if valid{
                    parseNMEA(fields: fields)
                    // The View should be updated by now
                }
            }
            return
        }
    }
    
    private func checksum(message: String, checksum: String) -> Bool {
        let messageLength = message.count
        let firstCharacter = message.first
        if messageLength < 5 || firstCharacter != "$"{
            return false
        }
        let actualMessage = message.slice(1, messageLength - 4)
        var calcChecksum = 0
        for c in actualMessage.utf8 {
            calcChecksum = calcChecksum ^ Int(c)
        }
        if calcChecksum == Int(checksum, radix: 16) ?? 999{
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    
    private func parseNMEA(fields: [String]){
        switch fields[0].slice(3, 5){
        case "MTW":
            nmea.mtw.src = fields[0].slice(1, 2)
            nmea.mtw.timeStamp = Date()
            nmea.mtw.temp = Double(fields[1]) ?? 0
            nmea.mtw.units = "º" + fields[2]
            print("MTW: \(nmea.mtw)")
        default:
            print("Missing sentence: \(fields[0].slice(1, 2))")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation

extension StringProtocol {
    func slice(_ start: Int, _ end: Int) -> String {
        if self.count >= end {
            let lower = index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: start)
            let upper = index(lower, offsetBy: end - start)
            return String(self[lower...upper])
        } else {
            return self as! String
        }
    }
}
```

Text file used for input:

```
$AIMTW,24.7,C*1A
$AIMTW,24.9,C*14
$AIMTW,24.8,C*15
$SDMTW,19.4,C*08
$AIMTW,24.9,C*14
$SDMTW,19.4,C*08
$SDMTW,19.4,C*08
$AIMTW,24.7,C*1A
$SDMTW,19.6,C*0A
$AIMTW,23.9,C*13
```

Comment: I may be wrong, I'm still trying to grasp The whole combine / swiftUI / MVVM thing after years of MVC, but I think you need to call objectWillChange.send() maybe in fetchNMEA()

Comment: Sorry @workingdog, I'm not sure what you mean (Still fairly new to this stuff). Aren't I updating nmea in parseNMEA() ?

Comment: Yes sorry, my mistake, I did not pay attention to `parseNMEA()`, I'll delete my comment.